# How can I prevent "Unknown column" errors between migration and deployment of RoR app on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

For my team's Heroku deployment, we first run migrations, then push to Heroku. When there is a migration that removes a column, in the time between the migration and the Heroku dynos running the new code, we experience the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'foo' in 'field list'`. We only remove a column long after it is no longer used (i.e. the code in production already does not need that column).

Our guess is that `config.cache_classes = true` being on in production is causing ActiveRecord to have a list of columns for the particular table.

Is there a way to safely remove a column during migration without having to restart any Heroku dynos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pedro knows, Check out this link for details surrounding how to get this done:

http://pedro.herokuapp.com/past/2011/7/13/rails_migrations_with_no_downtime/